# Movie where a guy has to escape a robot stopping him from leaving the junk yard he lives above

Tags: story-identification, movie

Trying to find movie where guy is staying in a house or blimp above a junkyard and he’s an inventor and someone comes along and they’re trying to escape but there's a robot or something in the junkyard stopping them from leaving. All I remember, is that it's a newer movie, at least 2010-2019.

Comment: Please go to https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question to get prompts to help you [edit] more detailed into the question.

Comment: Kannon Hicks, could you provide any more details on the movie? Please try to be specific.

Comment: I'll throw this in, but are you thinking of [Alita - Battle Angel] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alita%3A_Battle_Angel?